# Создать массив игроков и "проверить" их по очереди

Tags: java, android, массивы

Никак не могу создать массив игроков. 
В классе Team все установил, сеттеры, геттеры, конструктор и toString.
Сам массив вывел

```
public class Team {
private String name;
private int score;
private Player[] player;
```

Тут вопрос - почему у меня Player выделяется красным? (класс Main)

```
  Player[2] = new Player("Sa;", 4);
  Player[0] = new Player("Dn", 39);
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      Player[1].setName("Jason");
      Player[1].setName("Jason");
      Player[2].setSkills(5);
  }
```

Уже пытался писать имя после массива и т.д. и т.п. Подчеркивает именно Player. Если что - все классы уже создал, дело не в этом. Массив игроков надо создать в Team. 
Нужно обозначение массива чтобы по очереди "проверять" игроков через цикл. Если "проверять" можно без массивов - дайте мне знать.
Уже все перерыл и понять не могу как это все таки сделать. Буду очень благодарен. 
java

Comment: имя переменной `Player []` - `player` используйте его: `player[2]` и т.д.

Comment: Обращение к элементам массива происходит по имени переменной (у вас это `player` - с маленькой буквы. (Обычно массивы обзывают именами во множественном числе. Я бы обозвал `players`. Что происходит у вас в цикле вообще загадка. Что за массив `arr`? Зачем дважды в одну ячейку записывать? Что нужно "проверить"?

Comment: Вопрос вызван опечаткой, поэтому я советую его удалить.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Team {
    private static Player[] player;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        player = new Player[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < player.length; i++) {
            player[i] = new Player("Jordan"+i, i);
        }
        for (Player p : player){
            System.out.println(p.getName()+" -> "+p.getSkills());
        }
    }
    static class Player{
        private String name;
        private int skills;

        public Player(String name, int skills) {
            this.name = name;
            this.skills = skills;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public int getSkills() {
            return skills;
        }
        public void setSkills(int skills) {
            this.skills = skills;
        }
    }
}

Может чем помог код)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать цикл For Each. Он как раз работает с массивами. Ссылка на сайт с объяснениями - https://vertex-academy.com/tutorials/ru/cikl-for-each/